# angular material datepicker only opening once on google chrome when css theme file is included

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a weird issue. When I link one of the angular material prebuilt themes, indigo pink in my case, the datepicker control opens successfully once, adds the date to the proper input, and then will not open again if I use the toggle button to reopen again. It seems to work properly until I link the theme. I am using angular 7 with asp.net core and visual studio. Seetting up the datepicker is as follows:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="StartDatePicker" formControlName="StartDate" required placeholder="Start Date" >

<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="StartDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #StartDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
```

and the link tag in my head of index.html is as follows:

indigo-pink.css is in the assets folder. What am I doing wrong?